# Group case in a Switch/Case statement in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, switch-statement

I have a switch case where at different case may correspond the same fragment of code.

Is there an elegant alternative, rather than duplicating all the code ?

```
switch(expression) {

  case firstCase:
      // do something
      break;

  case secondCase:
      // do exactly the same of first case
      break;

  case otherCase:
      // do anything else
      break;

  case etceteraCase:
      .......


  default:
      break;

}
```

I know that as an alternative I could create a method to be called within the case, but this could lead to proliferation of methods hard to maintain.

Answer (score 7):

Yes:

```
switch(expression) {

  case firstCase:
  case secondCase:
      // do exactly the same of first case
      break;

  case otherCase:
  case yetAnotherCase:
      // do anything else
      break;

  case etceteraCase:
      .......


  default:
      break;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove break after first case:

```
switch(expression) {

  case firstCase:

  case secondCase:
      // do the same of first case
      break;

  case otherCase:
      // do anything else
      break;

  case etceteraCase:
      .......


  default:
      break;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
switch(expression) {

  case firstCase:
  case secondCase:
      // do exactly the same of first case
      break;

  case otherCase:
      // do anything else
      break;

  case etceteraCase:
      .......


  default:
      break;

}
```

excluding `break;` will produce your expected result.